# Passing const reference to Template Class that uses custom objects

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class I'm creating that takes in custom objects. It looks a little something like this.

```
template<typename T1,typename T2>
class myClass
{
public:
    myClass(const T1 &param1, const T2 &param2);
}



template<typename T1, typename T2>
myClass<T1,T2>::
myClass
(const T1 &param1, const T2 &param2)
{
    T1.customFunction(); //doesn't compile
}
```

So I expect that anytime this template class is used the person who uses it is responsible for making sure the class T1 has a function called customFunction(). Fair enough, the problem is customFunction must be guaranteed to be const at compile time since it's being called on a constant paramater (param1), but how can this even be possible if T1 is essentially a dummy class?

Answer (score 1):

First, it should be

```
param1.customFunction();
```

because you call it with the parameter object, not the type.

Secondly, you don't have to worry. Whenever you construct a `myClass` object, the compiler will check that the parameters you pass are of types where the member function is present and callable.

Answer (score 0):

You have got it slightly off: not the function must be "`const` at compile time", but the **types** that are passed must be known. The reason it does not compile is because you try to call `customFunction` on the type `T1` rather than on an instance of it.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
myClass<T1,T2>::
myClass
(const T1 &param1, const T2 &param2)
{
      param1.customFunction(); //does compile
};
```